# htaccess rewrite condition for vertical bar (pipe)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, google-crawlers

My Google Webmaster Tools show me hundreds of crawling errors of the following type:

```
/images/logo.jpg%7C
```

I can't find the source of the problem as the site seems to work fine so I was thinking if I could write a rewrite condition which alters all this url's to

```
/images/logo.jpg
```

This way it would work.

Can this be done with a rewrite condition in htaccess and if how?
Any other suggestions?

Comment: By any chance do you remember who was your DNS provider? We are seeing something similar and can't figure out why all of a sudden such requests are being crawled by `googlebot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\|$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This removes the vertical bar character from the end of the URL (any URL). The pipe symbol (vertical bar) needs to be backslash escaped in the regex to negate its special meaning.

Replace the `302` (temporary) with a `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK.

Comment: Hi @w3d, thank you for your help but unfortunately this doesn't work,
I am still getting the same error:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /images/logo.jpg| on this server.

Comment: Is this in the document root .htaccess file? Do you have any other directives in this file? The above directive will need to go at the top.

Comment: You were right, now I put it on the start of the htaccess and it works.
Thank you ver much @w3d

Comment: A small remark: at Windows platform this is not going to work. Read [**Bug 41441**](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41441) for more info.